# How to render or display a map from url

Tags: javascript, npm, openlayers, openlayers-3

in the below code which i copy it from:

```
https://openlayers.org/workshop/en/vector/geojson.html
```

as shown below, it needs the url:

```
url: './data/countries.json'
```

when i run the code no map appears inly plus and minus sign for zooming in and out with a dark blue background
please let me know how to find countries .json

**code**:

```
const map = new Map({
  target: 'map-container',
  layers: [
    new VectorLayer({
      source: new VectorSource({
        format: new GeoJSON(),
        url: './data/countries.json'
      })
    })
  ],
  view: new View({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    center: [13.063561,52.391842],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
```

**attempts**:

i also adapted the code to be as follows:

```
const vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: new VectorSource({
    url: './data/countries.geojson',
    format: new GeoJSON(),
    defaultProjection :'EPSG:4326', projection: 'EPSG:3857'
  })
})

const map = new Map({
  target: 'map-container',
  layers: [vectorLayer],
  view: new View({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    center: [0,0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
sync(map)
```

also tried

```
countries.json
         .geojson 
         .geo.json
```

but nothing gets displayed

Comment: You can download the "raw" file from https://github.com/openlayers/workshop/blob/master/src/en/data/countries.json and place it in your own data folder

Comment: @Mike would you please let me know how to download it??there is no downloag button

Comment: Open in raw mode and use the browser's "save" or "save as" option

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openlayers/workshop/master/src/en/data/countries.json

Comment: @syduki now i downloaded it as you suggested but nothing shows up...any idea how to fix it please

Comment: you should locate the `./data` directory in your application, and copy the file there

Comment: @syduki i did so and still not working

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors?

Comment: @geocodezip no errors..also i tried the drag and drop example and what is rendered is just as explained in the question above

Comment: Did you set up the workshop as instructed in the "Setup" section in https://openlayers.org/workshop/en/ ? If you do so, your initial code (not your other attempts - they all have mistakes in them) will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

For this code to work I have done the following:

I am **working on ubuntu** and I had **followed the instruction on** https://openlayers.org/workshop/en/ .

I **downloaded the folder** https://github.com/openlayers/workshop/releases/download/v6.0.0-beta.en.4/openlayers-workshop-en.zip from the workshop and extract it.

I went in the extracted folder and **run 'npm install'**.

I **wrote in the index.html file**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>OpenLayers</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-container {
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        background-color: #04041b;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```js
import 'ol/ol.css';
import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import View from 'ol/View';

new Map({
  target: 'map-container',
  layers: [
    new VectorLayer({
      source: new VectorSource({
        format: new GeoJSON(),
        url: './data/countries.json'
      })
    })
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
```

You can **run 'npm start'** at the root and it will work.

For the full tutorial I have done the following

At the root of the directory I **run the command 'npm install ol-hashed'**.

**I replaced the code in main.js**

```js
import 'ol/ol.css';
import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import View from 'ol/View';

import sync from 'ol-hashed';


const map = new Map({
  target: 'map-container',
  layers: [
    new VectorLayer({
      source: new VectorSource({
        format: new GeoJSON(),
        url: './data/countries.json'
      })
    })
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
sync(map);
```

**Run 'npm start'** and it will work.

Now **if you want to work with the url of geojson** you need the link to the raw data.

In this case I used https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openlayers/workshop/master/src/en/data/countries.json

and **change my code in main.js** by

```js
import 'ol/ol.css';
import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import View from 'ol/View';

import sync from 'ol-hashed';


const map = new Map({
  target: 'map-container',
  layers: [
    new VectorLayer({
      source: new VectorSource({
        format: new GeoJSON(),
        url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openlayers/workshop/master/src/en/data/countries.json' // here is the link
      })
    })
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});
sync(map);
```

**If the map doesn't show it mean that the argument in 'url' is wrong.
You can check in your browser console if there is an error.**